# PhpStorm: How to access and modify remain string in "Replace in Path" dialog inputs?

Tags: replace, dialog, find, phpstorm, finddialog

I use PhpStorm 2017.2

I want to replace some function codes with a new code string and I want to add `\n` to some parts of the string in Replace in Path inputs but I can't see or modify remain of the string.

[image]

my replace string is:     `function test_pr()    {        if(confirm('Are You sure to run this action???'))\n            window.open('.?pm=32&yu=876&cid=dkjgkfdhgjfdhg63ufb4uft4745y$clo=t546gy677', '_self');    }` that I cant see and modify after `$clo=t546gy677'` and cant scroll forward input contents in "Replace in Path" Dialog.

**How can I access and modify remain string in "Replace in Path" dialog inputs?**

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly but what happens (or not) exactly? Do the PhpStorm accept the keyboard input in "Replace" field? How long the query is?

Comment: @duck_in_hat my replace string is:     `function test_pr()    {        if(confirm('Are You sure to run this action???'))\n            window.open('.?pm=32&yu=876&cid=dkjgkfdhgjfdhg63ufb4uft4745y$clo=t546gy677', '_self');    }` that I cant see and modify after `$clo=t546gy677'` and cant scroll forward input contents in "Replace in Path" Dialog...

Comment: @sidoco What if you edit your replacement text in advance and then paste it into that field? Other than that: consider upgrading your IDE as current versions support multi-line editing in those fields and scrollers.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, Every time I have to use text editor or PhpStorm empty page to edit and paste into replace input, and I think maybe has any settings to increase visible writing input space.